What to learn for Java after AP CSA
I finished my AP CSA class this year where we learned the structural basics of Java. Mainly the different variables, using methods, different loops, arrays, and array lists etc. What should I learn next to start building applications?

Software engineering (& RTE).

It's quite possible that you are not that interested in an answer this long after asking your question, but in case you are still interested, here are my thoughts.
Since you specifically asked about Java, I am going to assume that you plan to continue exploring Java. I suggest developing an understanding about how to use JUnit to test your code. Whether you move toward a test-driven development mindset or not, including automated tests in your code is a way to communicate the functionality of your code, to be sure that the expected behavior has not been broken by changes, and to prevent yourself from missing edge cases (assuming that you characterize and capture those edge cases in tests). Writing tests that initially fail (but capture the expected behavior) and then writing the code to make those tests pass can be a way to ensure that you are writing just the right amount of code to make your program work. When you think of more behaviors to add, capture those behaviors by creating tests and then implement just enough to make the new tests pass.
A second thing to consider is learning how to use a project manager such as Maven to help manage dependencies and make your code a bit more portable. I have found in teaching computer science courses at the level you describe that students are often ready for programs that include multiple files and dependencies. Maven and Gradle have both worked well for me as a way to capture the requirements for running lab code on a variety of computers without as much worry about setup, but I think Maven is a little easier to understand.
